# Restore default ppa settings

Tags: ppa

I accidentally removed a ppa and now I am unable to download any app from app center. How can resolve it? Also I don't remember the ppa, it was just the last one in the list.

Comment: How did you remove it? From command line?

Comment: no from the software and updates app

Comment: I was removing some ppas that I added to use gnome 13.16.

Answer (score 2):

If you added the PPA from the command line, you should be able to find (and re-run) the command with `history | grep add-apt-repository`.

But there are no "default PPA settings".  They are personal package archives; the default is *no* PPAs, so it's unlikely removing one would cause your symptom "unable to download any app from app center."

If you need to replace your default **main** source settings (e.g. /etc/apt/sources.list), this online tool can generate the files for you: http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it started working after a reboot.